# undefined method `at_css' for #<String:0x007fe9ac5ae310> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get all of my prices in my array of URLS, getting the values with a CSS selector.
The thing is, the method at_css is giving me the following error:

**undefined method `at_css' for string (NoMethodError)**

Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
test = ["www.myweb.com/1", "www.myweb.com/2"]

    test.each do |item|

      Nokogiri::HTML(open(item))

      puts item.at_css('.itemprice').text

      puts item.at_css('.description').text

      puts "Empty Line"

    end
```

Comment: `item` is a string. Checking your types is step 1 of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The `item` variable in your block is a string i.e. an element from your `test` array variable. And strings don't have a `to_css` method in Ruby. You probably wanted to call the `to_css` on some Nokogiri-related object.

I think you need the following:

```
some_var = Nokogiri::HTML(open(item))
some_var.at_css('.itemprice').text
```

Comment: That was it. I had to create a var inside to target a Nokogiri object. Thanks!!